# Infinite loop warning in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, directive

This vue directive:

```
Vue.directive 'datepicker',
  bind: () ->
    vm = this.vm
    key = this.expression
    datepicker = $(this.el).datepicker
      todayBtn: 'linked'
      language: 'de'
      daysOfWeekDisabled: '0'
      calendarWeeks: true
      todayHighlight: true
      toggleActive: true
      autoclose: true
    datepicker.on 'changeDate', (e) ->
      vm.$set key, e.date
  update: (val) ->
    $(this.el).datepicker 'setDate', val
```

gives me this warning in the console:

```
You may have an infinite update loop for watcher with expression: date
```

for the line

```
vm.$set key, e.date
```

How can I get rid of the warning / infinite loop?

Comment: Try removing that line and the one above that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a guard on your `changeDate` handler to update `vm` only when the date is really different than the one already stored. Please note that identity check may not be enough as `$datepicker` (depending on its internal implementation) can dispatch `changeDate` event with a copy of date.